# Producing stacked 3D blocks using TikZ

Tags: deep-learning, latex, tikz

I have started to learn TikZ for producing figures however I am still being limited to very simple drawings (lines, texts, etc.). Almost all the figures I need to build will ressemble 3D rectangular blocks following each other with sometimes writing on it or arrows like in this image:[image], (which I took from https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02921 )

It reads really well. I was wondering if there were modular building blocks allowing to draw this kinds of figures ? Or if one needed to be extremely competent with TikZ beforehand and no shortcut are available. (I am open to other alternatives than TikZ if well defended)

**EDIT:** As I said I am looking for modular blocks in TikZ and examples syntax to create stacked 3D blocks not a perfect code allowing to build exactly the attached figure (although it would be incredible).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For all of my "3D tikz drawing", I've been using the parallelepiped shape from [this tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/network-topology/). From that you can build basic 3D shapes of any color, size, etc.

My initial work on your example (it's the exact code I used on overleaf.com) and the corresponding image are below. There'd still be a lot of work needed to achieve the exact same result (arrow that goes above the middle blocks, plus sign, different colors on sides, text font, etc.).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1f4e79}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{00b0f0}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{ff9c6b}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows,positioning,decorations.markings,backgrounds,arrows.meta}

% Define parallelepiped shape:
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  % Dark blue blocks
  block/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.8cm,
    minimum height=2.4cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=darkblue,bottom color=darkblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Orange-ish blocks
  conv/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.8cm,
    minimum height=2.4cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=salmon,bottom color=salmon]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Taller Light blue blocks:
  plate/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.1cm,
    minimum height=7.4cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=lightblue,bottom color=lightblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Arrows between blocks:
  link/.style={
    color=lightblue,
    line width=2mm,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % The order of blocks matters since some are partially hidden behind subsequent blocks.
  \node[conv](conv1){\rotatebox{90}{Conv}};
  \node[plate,right=0.2cm of conv1](plate1){};
  % yshift to align the bottom of that blocks with the previous taller block.
  \node[block,right=0.2cm of plate1,yshift=-2.5cm](resblock1){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock}};
  \node[block,above=0.1cm of resblock1](resblock2){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock}};
  \node[block,above=0.1cm of resblock2](resblock3){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock}};
  \node[block,right=0.2cm of resblock1](x1){\rotatebox{90}{(X4)}};
  \node[block,above=0.1cm of x1](x2){\rotatebox{90}{(X3)}};
  \node[block,above=0.1cm of x2](x3){\rotatebox{90}{(X2)}};
  \node[plate,right=0.2cm of x2](plate2){};
  \node[block,right=0.6cm of x2](resblock4){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock4}};
  \node[block,right=2cm of resblock4](resblock5){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock5}};
  \node[conv,right=0.2cm of resblock5](conv2){\rotatebox{90}{Conv}};
  \draw [-,link] ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=0.2cm]resblock4.east) -- ([yshift=0.2cm]resblock5.west);
  \draw [-triangle 60,link] ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=0.2cm]conv2.east) -- ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.2cm]conv2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Waouh impressive ! I did not even think someone would get so close ! Still working through your code but looks legit ! this class parallelepiped seems to be exactly the building block I need ! Very impressed.

Comment: Accepting your answer at the end of the week I really think your answer will become a reference for lots of people ! Way to go !

Comment: Glad I could help!